# Session object destruction failed if idle

Tags: php, session

Currently I use [Secure Session](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2794-PHP-Prevent-session-hijacking-or-session-fixation.html) to authorize into the members area. The class is working fine  , but there is a problem when a user is idle.

Let's say I'm logged into the members area and am idle for 10 or 15 minutes, after that when I click any link on the members area `session_regenerate_id(true)` is not working and showing `Session object destruction failed`.

```
function _RegenerateId()
    {
        if ($this->regenerate_id && function_exists('session_regenerate_id')) {
            if (version_compare(phpversion(), '5.1.0', '>=')) {
                session_regenerate_id(true);
            } else {
                session_regenerate_id();
            }
        }
    }
```

Sometimes when file loading takes too long the same error will appear.

What is causing this?

Comment: has this been resolved ?